# ¿Cómo asigno un nombre al exportar una tabla a Excel desde C# devexpress?

Tags: c#, excel, devexpress

Quiero que al exportar un Excel, también pueda asignar un nombre a la tabla que envío.

```
try
     {
       ClassResultPV cr;
         {
                    CtrTareo ctr = new CtrTareo();
                    cr = ctr.Pln_CargarDiasConceptuales(new DtoTareo()
                    {
                        RucE = Globales.RucEmp,
                        Ejer = Globales.EjeEmp,
                        Prdo = Globales.Prdo,
                        TipPlan = Globales.TipoPlanilla == TipPlanilla.Empleados ? "E" : "O",
                        Sem = Globales.TipoPlanilla == TipPlanilla.Empleados ? null : Globales.Semana,
                        Usu = Globales.UsuActual,
                        Cd_ModContrato = chkModContrato.Visible == true ? HelpPV.ObtenerCodidoStr_CheckedComboBoxEdit(chkModContrato, ',') : null
                    });
                    dtdc = cr.DT;
                    gcDiasConcep.DataSource=dtdc;
                }
                try
                {
                    Utiles.ExportarGridDevExpress(gvDiasConcep, "Formato de Importación Días Conceptuales", ExportXtraGrid.Export,true);
                    //List<GridControl> ogrid = new List<GridControl>();
                    //ogrid.Add(gcDiasConcep);
                    //List<String> otits = new List<String>();
                    //otits.Add("Formato de Importación Días Conceptuales");
                    //List<StringAlignment> lSA = new List<StringAlignment>();
                    //lSA.Add(StringAlignment.Near);

                    //Utiles.ExportarGridExcel(ogrid.ToArray(), otits.ToArray(), lSA.ToArray(), "Formato de Importación Días Conceptuales", false);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Si tu grid es [DevExpress] deberias añadir el tag a la pregunta, y al título tambén.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el codigo que exporta a excel, lo tienes dentro del método "Utiles.ExportarGridDevExpress".

Necesitarías poner el código de ese método, para ver como exportas el excel.